# Heroku Apscheduler: timed job OK but not for schedulee job

Tags: heroku, apscheduler

I am following [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-python#apscheduler) to schedule my Django cron job on Heroku.

`Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn tango.wsgi --log-file -
clock: python createStatistics.py
```

`createStatistics.py`:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

sched = BlockingScheduler()

@sched.scheduled_job('interval', minutes=1)
def timed_job():
    print('This job is run every minute.')

@sched.scheduled_job('cron', day=14, hour=15, minute=37)
def scheduled_job():
    print('This job is run on day 14 at minute 37, 3pm.')

sched.start()
```

The `timed_job` runs OK, however, the `scheduled_job` has no effect. Do I need to set up any time zone information for `apscheduler` (I have the TIME_ZONE set in `settings.py`)? If so, how? Or did I miss anything?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this setup. Have you tried enabling debug logging (setting up the logging system with level=DEBUG)? That will tell you when the next job is scheduled to be run. If you only schedule scheduled_job, it will then tell you how long you need to wait. You can use this information to check if the schedule looks right.

Answer (score 0):

Specific to Heroku, for reasons I have not been able to figure out yet, it seems that you need to specify the optional id field on cron jobs to make them work. So the cron, job definition would now look like this.

```py
@sched.scheduled_job('cron', id="job_1", day=14, hour=15, minute=37)
def scheduled_job():
    print('This job is run on day 14 at minute 37, 3pm.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the timezone in every job otherwise Heroku will run in **UTC** timezone.

```
@sched.scheduled_job('cron', day=14, hour=15, minute=37, timezone=YOUR_TIME_ZONE)
def scheduled_job():
    print('This job is run on day 14 at minute 37, 3pm.')
```